# Why send a class through +(Class)class before calling a class method?

Tags: objective-c

I've been browsing Sketch, an example program they ship with Xcode, and I keep seeing things like this (not always though):

```
[[MyClass class] classMethod]
```

Now, since `MyClass` isn't an instance of the class, I would just do:

```
[MyClass classMethod]
```

As an experiment though, I was able to make a difference between the two above statements, by overriding `+ (Class)class` and returning *another* class! If you ever want to do this, you would need the former version for it to work, so I can see that there **could** be a usage for this, but is there really?

It sounds like an awful idea tampering like this with `+class`, but please enlighten me if there is. Thanks!

---

To see some examples, check out the method `-copy:` in `SKTGraphicsView.m` in the Sketch program found in `Developer/Examples/Sketch/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case that you cited, I don't really see any good reason for calling `+class`. However, there is *definitely* a case for calling `[[self class] doSomething]` instead of `[[MyClass class] doSomething]`. In the first case, `[self class]` can return the correct result if the object has been subclassed. In the second case, you will always get the `MyClass` class object, which means that `MySubClass` could not effectively override the `+doSomething` class method.

Comment: I agree, but I'm still puzzled as to what's going on in the cited case. I mean, you could do something similar to this, by subclassing `MyClass`, and then overriding `+class` to point to the new class. This does not strike me as good design though.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as I don't think there was any particularly good reason for their usage of `+class`. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

There is no good reason for using `+class` in that case. `+class` simply returns the object (the class object) that it is called on, same as `-self`. In most cases, people use `[SomeClass class]` to get the class object for a class, because the name of a class is not an expression, and can only be used as the receiver in the message calling syntax as a special case. Therefore, in all other contexts, they use `[SomeClass class]` to get the class object as an expression (although `[SomeClass self]` would also work equally well).

In the case you showed, it is redundant, because it is the receiver of a message. I am guessing they did it out of habit or ignorance (they thought that you must always write `[SomeClass class]` to use the class).